# Blank White Screen for iframes in phonegap App

Tags: phonegap-build

I have an html5 mobile responsive website. In this website, I am showing iframes (in many pages) of asp.net pages that are hosted externally. If I view the html5 website in browser either in PC or mobile, it is displaying all the pages correctly.

I had converted this html5 website to android app using phonegap build (cloud one). It was working fine for last few months. Few days back I had added some new pages to the html5 website using iframes to show new asp.net pages. I tried updating the phonegap through build.phonegap.com. Now when I open the android app, what i see is blank white screens in place of all iframes. I don't know what happened but I think phonegap version was updated to cli-5.2.0 (3.9.1/4.1.1/3.8.1).

Could this be the issue? How can I revert back to the old version? I tried specifying in config.xml but no success. I even searched online for solutions but I couldn't find solution to my problem. I have allowed in config.xml. I found in some site that we need to allow access for domains and subdomains. So I tried doing that but no success. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am successful in solving my problem by specifying version 3.7.1 in config.xml